# SQL Server 2012 Compatibility with New TLS 1.2 Standards

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to switch off TLS 1.0 on my SQL Server 2012 server in order to comply with PCI standards.

Initially I had some trouble with the SQL Server service not starting.

I've found help online on other sites and discussions but I'm having mixed results:

This is what I've done so far:

I have downloaded SQL Server 2012 Cumulative Update 7 (CU 6 also works) and the SQL Server Service then starts correctly.

I had a problem not being able to sign in to the DB instance through SQL Server Enterprise Manager which was fixed by installing .Net 4.6.

Next problem, client computer running IIS Application is unable to connect to SQL instance because of a 'handshaking SSL error'. I followed advice and installed the latest SNAC native client.

This was difficult to track down and the latest version available as a download from Microsoft was from 2014. I then obtained sqlnclient.msi dated 9/7/2015 revision number {E6CB4138-3D1C-4ADC-95C4-88322B60FC14} from a sub folder generated by the extract of CU 7 - "Path to Extract Folder \1033_enu_lp\x64\setup\x64".

I've updated this version of the Native client on my IIS server (and .Net 4.6) and I'm still unable to connect remotely to the SQL instance. If I enable TLS 1.0 I'm able to connect.

The exact error I'm getting is 'A connection was sucessfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake'.

My diagnosis is I don't have the correct version of SNAC on my machine compatible with TLS 1.2 and the CU 7 as the client and server cannot handshake. However, this sqlnclient.msi was extracted from the CU 7 and I cannot find a more up to date copy.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? What version of the SNAC are you using? Where did you get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As of January 29th, Microsoft SQL Server supports TLS 1.2 for SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014 and major client drivers like Server Native Client, Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server, Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server and ADO.NET (SqlClient).

Blog post about the release: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2016/01/29/tls-1-2-support-for-sql-server-2008-2008-r2-2012-and-2014.aspx

List of builds that support TLS 1.2 along with the client and server component download locations (KB3135244): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3135244

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the client update from the KB (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052468)
Package name: 2012_SP2_SNAC_CU6_3052468_11_0_5592_x64

Download link: http://support2.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=3052468&kbln=en-us

What is the provider name in your IIS site?

You will need the KB3052468 update both for the client and the server. They are available on the hotfix download link provided.